# PHP foreach weirdness with multi-dim array sent over AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, foreach

I'm guessing this is some known issue I've just somehow never come across. I have a multi-dimensional array being sent over AJAX to PHP as follows:

```
let pd = {
    vids: $.map(yt_vids_preview.find('tr:has(td :checked)'), function(el) {
        let vid = $(el).data('vid');
        return {
            vid_id: vid.contentDetails.videoId
    }; })
};
$.ajax({data: pd, url: 'foo.php', type: 'post'})
```

Here's what PHP receives, according to `print_r($_POST['vids'])`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [vid_id] => kCkrVN7IVbo
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [vid_id] => dNVxfnb8fjo
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [vid_id] => rJEEYTzYiAE
        )
)
```

All good. Three different videos.

Now for the weirdness.

```
foreach($_POST['vids'] as $arr) echo $arr['vid_id']."\n";
```

For some reason, this outputs:

```
kCkrVN7IVbo
dNVxfnb8fjo
dNVxfnb8fjo
```

One of the items has been duplicated, at the expensive of another, which has been omitted completely. I've omitted all other code and there's no overwriting of `$arr` or anything like that.

This doesn't happen if I use a basic `for()` loop, or even iterative callback functions like `array_walk()`:

```
array_walk($_POST['vids'], function($arr) { echo $arr['vid_id']."\n"; });
```

Gives:

```
kCkrVN7IVbo
dNVxfnb8fjo
rJEEYTzYiAE
```

What on earth is going on?

Comment: Have you done something like this before the code you are showing? `foreach($vids as &$arr) $arr['vid_id'] = $something;`

Comment: @AramilRey D'oh, you're right, though I wouldn't have expected the problem it's causing. Posting the answer now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the foreach loop you are showing in your question, and the one in your answer:

```
// First
foreach($_POST['vids'] as $i => &$arr) {
    //...
}

// Second
foreach($_POST['vids'] as $arr) echo $arr['vid_id']."\n";
```

The first loop creates a reference between `$arr` and every element of `$_POST['vids']`, but the reference to the last element is never unset, so `$arr` is actually still referencing the last element of the array

This might sound somewhat unintuitive, but what it means, is that the last element of the `$_POST['vids']` changes when you change the value of `$arr`, so at the last iteration on `$_post['vids']`,  you are esentially doing `$arr = $arr` which value was what you asigned on the previous iteration of the loop.

Graphically, something like this is happening. (this is not valid PHP)

```
$arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 <=> $value] 
// This represents the last item on arr being a reference of $value (<=> is not being used as an actual operator, its representing the reference)

foreach($arr as $value) {
    echo $arr;
}
// OUTPUT:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1 <=> $value] // $value equals the first element of the array
[1, 2, 3, 4, 2 <=> $value] // $value equals the 2nd element of the array
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3 <=> $value] // $value equals the 3rd element
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4 <=> $value] // $value equals the 4th element
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4 <=> $value] // $value equals itself (4th element)
```

To solve this, you just need to break the reference before the 2nd loop by using `unset($arr)`

```
unset($arr);
foreach($_POST['vids'] as $arr) echo $arr['vid_id']."\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is likely to help anyone else but it turns out a previous use of `$arr` in a `foreach()` loop, much earlier in the same function, was to blame.

Crucially, this one was assigned via reference, i.e.

```
foreach($_POST['vids'] as $i => &$arr) {
    //...
}
```

For some reason I don't fully understasnd, this caused the problem when I later used `$arr` in a different `foreach()` assignment. I get that it's leaking from the earlier referential assignment, but why duplicate one and omit another video ID? Weird result...

```
foreach($_POST['vids'] as $arr) echo $arr['vid_id']."\n";
```

Comment: The reference variable is not unset after the loop ends. So it always is referring to the last element of the `$_POST['vids']` array. The subsequent `foreach` overwrites this last array bucket at each iteration; essentially the `foreach` is assigning a value to the `$arr` variable (which is a reference) at each iteration.

Comment: Posted my own answer, hope it helps you to understand how the reference was causing this issue!